# Get IP address of node returned by chef search in recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

How can I get IP address returned by node search in chef recipe (ruby).

```ruby
dbnodes = search(:node, "role:Db")
Chef::Log.info(dbnodes.first["ipaddress"]) # nil
```

Few weeks ago this code returned IP of first instance from search API.

version: Chef: 10.14.2

Answer (score 10):

I'm guessing that you're new to Ruby.  If so, welcome!

The Chef `search()` function returns an array of Chef nodes and you are taking the head of this array using the `first` method.  To access the IP address of the other nodes use the regular array operator:

```
dbnodes = search(:node, "role:Db")
dbnodes.each do |node|
  Chef::Log.info("#{node["name"]} has IP address #{node["ipaddress"]}")
end
```

This should give you the information you need.

Comment: I think by saying "this code returned IP of **first** instance from search API" Matej meant exactly the same.

Comment: So for getting ips of nodes we have to assign some roles or environment as pattern to search nodes right ?. Suppose i have not assigned any role or environment just configured 3 clients with server so is there any way to get ips of these clients.

Comment: You can get a list of all nodes using a different search command.  Try `search(:node, "*:*")`.