# Get specific IP address for each Chef server node

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Please excuse as I am new to both Chef & Ruby.  This should be an easy question.  Following along with [Jason Grimes's Tutorial](http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/06/deploying-a-lamp-application-with-chef-vagrant-and-ec2-3-of-3/).

How do I remove **localhost** and instead use the specific IP address of a Chef node in the code below?

`# Get a list of web servers

webservers = node['roles'].include?('webserver') ? [{'ipaddress' => 'localhost'}] : search(:node, "role:webserver AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}")`

Can I instead substitute

`webservers = search(:node, "role:webserver AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}")`

since IP_address is an [automatic attribute according to Opscode](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Automatic+Attributes) and this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337110/get-ip-address-of-node-returned-by-chef-search-in-recipe).

Unfortunately I don't quite understand how I would test this to be sure otherwise I would have run a test.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

```
webservers = search(:node, "role:webserver AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}")
```

then `webservers` will be an array of nodes and you will be able to obtain IP by

```
webservers[index]['ipaddress']
```